# XAML C# - Combobox con Background y Foreground, no entiendo el funcionamiento

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, xaml, .net-core

Estoy trabajando desde Visual Studio 2019
Sobre C# .NET core 3.1 WPF

He definido un `Combobox` con `Background` y `Foreground`.
Cuando cargo la aplicacion, los `Textbox` funcionan perfectos pero el `Combobox` "no hace lo esperado"

¿que es lo que se me escapa?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Codigo XAML

```
<Label Foreground="#FFF4F4F4" Content="Natural or Synthetic:" Margin="0,0,0,2"></Label>
<ComboBox x:Name="CB_natOsyn" Background="#FF3A3A3A" Foreground="#FFF4F4F4"
          OpacityMask="#FF3A3A3A">
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF3A3A3A" IsSelected="True">Natural</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF3A3A3A">Synthetic</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITO: a petición de **Juan Salvador Portugal**

Lo que estoy intentando hacer y no consigo es.

Que el ComboBox tenga los mismos colores de BackGround que el TextBox que se muestra en la imagen.
Ya que cuando se carga la aplicación, el formulario que se muestra en pantalla, muestra los combobox con background en blanco.

Gracias.

Comment: agrega el texto como propiedad <ComboBoxItem  Content="Natural"  IsSelected="True"

Comment: Nada, mismo resultado.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CB_natOsyn" Background="#FF3A3A3A" Foreground="#FFF4F4F4" OpacityMask="#FF3A3A3A">
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF3A3A3A">Natural</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF3A3A3A" IsSelected="True">Synthetic</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: existe algun metodo que afecte al combo box CB_natOsyn ?

Comment: No ninguno. Si eliminamos x:Name="CB_natOsyn", no cambia su comportamiento.

Comment: elimina completamete el item box natural,copia y pega el syntetic y cambiale el texto. Haz un clean al cache de blender o visual studio y recompila

Comment: No se como hacer el CLEAN CACHE de Visual Studio. --- De todas formas, hice un proyecto nuevo y presenta el mismo problema exacto.

Comment: subue tu proyecto a git y comparte la liga para descargarlo y revisarlo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104340/discussion-between-miguel-zarate-and-jorge-perez).

Comment: Ya en el chat. ;)

Comment: Jorge, podrías editar la pregunta explicando que es lo que "no funciona como se espera" porque tanto el código, como la imagen se ven correctos..

Comment: Si, ahora lo hago.